# Javascript to enhance parameterized builds

Tags: javascript, jenkins

The 'parameterized' builds in Jenkins are a bit limited. What if I want to have options that are related to one another?

For example 2 drop down lists. The selection from the first one controls the options in the second...

I don't really see any prescribed way to implement this, but a thought (and it feels super-hacky) would be to use javascript.

I've noticed you can enter `<script>` tags in the *description* attribute of parameters. Maybe a place to drop in some js? Also looks like prototype.js ships with the system.

So just how bad an idea is that, or is there a 'correct' way to do such a thing?

Comment: I posted [the question on the Google group for Jenkins dev](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-dev/kzlCBknbpHU). Sounds like there really isn't anything out there for this, but another person said an interface to configure parameter relationships would be nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the Active Choices Plugin it does exactly what you're looking for:

[jenkins-ci.org - Active Choices Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Active+Choices+Plugin)
[github.com - Active Choices Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/active-choices-plugin)

> A Jenkins UI plugin for generating and rendering multiple value
> options for a job parameter. The parameter options can be dynamically
> generated from a Groovy script and can respond to changes in other job
> parameters. The value options can be rendered as combo-boxes,
> check-boxes, radio-buttons or rich HTML. Active Choices strives to
> provide in a single plugin functionality found scattered among several
> pre-existing plugins and some unique capabilities that are not
> available yet.
>
> The Active Choices plug-in provides additional Jenkins
> parameter types that can be rendered as user interface (UI) controls
> in job forms.
>
> Once the plugin is installed three new parameter types become
> available:
>
> - Active Choices Parameter
> - Active Choices Reactive Parameter
> - Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter
>
> Active Choices parameters allow users to select value(s) for a job parameter. Parameter values can be:
>
> - dynamically generated (using Groovy or a Scriptler script)
> - dynamically updated based on other UI parameters
> - multi-valued (can have more than one value)
> - rendered with a variety of UI controls, including dynamic HTML

Comment: Very cool, I'll take a look! Not super-stoked about using groovy, but probably not that much of a learning curve (the examples look straightforward). I also notice that this plugin is very new, 1.0 was tagged on Jun of this year, so this wasn't out when I first asked the question.

Answer (score 2):

I think you would be able to accomplish your listed example with the following dynamic parameters plugin without using javascript: https://github.com/tekante/Dynamic-Jenkins-Parameter/wiki. I have not personally used the plugin as a disclaimer. It looks like it will probably need to be built first based on what I have seen in the GitHub repo and the fact that I cannot find it on the official Jenkins plugin page.

Comment: This is a decent starting point, though I'm unsure I want to compile it from source, I might give it a try though. Generally my question is asking for more than just the related drop-down-lists. I want _interactivity_ in general. For example, if one of the boolean options (a checkbox) is checked, I might want to force the selection of a particular option in a drop-down-list. Currently, the hacky JS 'solution' seems to be the best, less its lack of reliability.